# How to connect to my phone via bluetooth serial

Tags: embedded, bluetooth, bluez

I am having trouble connecting to my phone via serial bluetooth on an embedded linux system. Here are the steps that I have taken to attempt a connection. (Note that I am able to pair and connect just fine using bluetoothctl)

OS: Linux nitrogen6x 4.1.15-2.0.0-ga+yocto+g651db0b #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 16 15:53:27 PST 2017 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

```
root@embeddedsystem:~# echo 0 > /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/state
root@embeddedsystem:~# echo 1 > /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/state 
root@embeddedsystem:~# hciattach -t 30 -s 115200 /dev/ttymxc2 texas 3000000 flow
Found a Texas Instruments' chip!
Firmware file : /lib/firmware/ti-connectivity/TIInit_7.6.15.bts
Loaded BTS script version 1
texas: changing baud rate to 3000000, flow control to 1
Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
Device setup complete
root@embeddedsystem:~# hciconfig hci0 up
root@embeddedsystem:~# hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1 //simple pairing

//Enable controller
root@embeddedsystem:~# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# default-agent
[bluetooth]# quit

root@embeddedsystem:~# rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA 22
root@embeddedsystem:~# sdptool add --channel=22 SP //Serial port on channel 22
root@embeddedsystem:~# rfcomm //check to see if channel is ok
rfcomm0: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA channel 22 clean
root@embeddedsystem:~# rfcomm connect /dev/rfcomm0 AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA 22
Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused
```

Here is where I get stuck. I have no idea why the connection is being refused when I can connect without problems using bluetoothctl (confirmed on my phone). It took me awhile to get here so I am not exactly sure what is the difference between bluetoothctl and rfcomm. From poking around I just see that you need to use rfcomm to get a serial connection. All I want to do is to grab my phone contacts from my phone using command line. I guess I am also asking if it is achievable to get my phone contacts without using rfcomm but using a connection through bluetoothctl.

P.S. If anyone knows how to grab files from my phone via command line without using OBEX I would appreciate it as well!